# The conditional request failed with Dynamodb add operation

Tags: database, java

I am using Dynamodb to perform the Add operation of new user, but I got some ConditionalCheckFailedException while saving the data.

I checked online and got to knew , like if we are using some condition then there might be a chance that we are conflicting with the data.

So I refactor my code and remove the saveExpression.setConditionalOperator(ConditionalOperator.AND) condition.

But After that I am getting the same issue:

```
{
  "errorCode": 500,
  "message": "The conditional request failed (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ConditionalCheckFailedException; Request ID: LN5P87FREI8SP1EIG4C9O60OUVVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9LSMANOG; Proxy: null)"
}
```

I want to know what are the other factor that raised this issue ?

Attaching my DB code :

```
  @Override
    public Optional<Item> addUser(@NonNull final Item userItem) {
        DynamoDBSaveExpression saveExpression = new DynamoDBSaveExpression();
        Map<String, ExpectedAttributeValue> expectedAttributes =
                Map.of("UserId", new ExpectedAttributeValue(false));
        saveExpression.setExpected(expectedAttributes);
        super.save(userItem, saveExpression);
        return super.load(Item.class, userItem.getUserId())
```

Comment: Can anyone provide some suggestion here, still facing the issue?